# How to convert nanosecond to seconds in transcripts of Google Cloud Speech to text API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-speech-to-text-api, transcription

I want to see seconds instead of nanoseconds in my transcript results, is there a way to do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thyFi.png)

here are my config codes

```
media_uri = 'gs://gcs_audio_files/newaudio.wav'
long_audi_wav = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=media_uri)

config_wav_enhanced = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
    enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
    enable_word_time_offsets=True,
    language_code='fil-PH',
    use_enhanced=True
)

config_wav = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
    enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
    enable_word_time_offsets=True,
    language_code='fil-PH',
    profanity_filter = True,    
    #Settings = 'Profanity',
)

operation = speech_client.long_running_recognize(
    config = config_wav,
    audio=long_audi_wav
)

response = operation.result(timeout=90)
print(response)
```

I tried searching and I found that people usually have "seconds" in their transcript instead of nanoseconds. I'm wondering what I did wrong?

```
enable_word_time_offsets=True,
```

My word_time_offsets is enabled. I would appreciate any feedbacks. Thanks!

Comment: 1 second = 1,000,000,000 nanoseconds (or 1e9 nanoseconds).  use this conversion....

Comment: D.L, which part should I add that conversion?